# SSIS Visual C# Script Component to access SPO List

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ssis, csom

I have written all of the code into a console solution and it executes fine.  When I try to bring that code over into an SSIS script component as a source I get the following error.

[Script Component Runtime Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw1vd.png)

I am including the small portion of my code I am trying to test as well.  This code has been trimmed down to the point where the error occurs.  I have tested this exact code in a console solution and it executes without any errors.

```
   public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        string siteURL = "https://XXXXXXXXX.sharepoint.com/XXXXXX";
        string userName = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        string password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";

        //Create the client context object and set the credentials  
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL);
        SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();

        foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);

        clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);

        //Load the web  
        Web web = clientContext.Web;

        clientContext.Load(web);

        List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        clientContext.Load(oList);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.Match = "TRUTH";
    }
```

Comment: First thing I would try is to rule out permission issues; is it the same client machine/user where you test from console and SSIS?

Comment: Yes, same machine and network.  I literally pasted the code from one window to the next 2 minutes before I posted the question.

Comment: Do you need to use any additional libraries? If so, are they not saving after you close your script task? I just ran into this problem recently.

Comment: Hi Tony, I had this problem initially and so I added my libraries to the GAC and no longer got the missing reference issue.  That is when this problem popped up.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.  I decided to see what kind of luck I would have with an OData source and started having validation errors.  I found this was due to an issue of DotNet 4.6 not defaulting to TLS1.2 like it should an the solutions was to make 2 registry entries.  The details can be found here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dataaccesstechnologies/tls-issue-with-ssis-package-while-accessing-odata-source-like-dynamics-ax-online

Thank you all for your assistance.

Kind Regards

Comment: glad you found a solution, thanks for sharing it